# ByteBuffer parse unsigned int

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I am working with java.nio in Java 8.
I receive an unsigned int inside the buffer and i want to save it as such, but i get a negative number.

```
final int shouldBePositive = buffer.getInt();
```

and shouldBePositive is negative.

Is there a way to work around the fact Java doesn't have unsigned int type?

Comment: "I want to save it" what exactly does this mean? If you want to convert it to a String you can use `Integer.toUnsignedString`.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to work around that fact. It's not pretty, though.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from simply living with this, you could always use a `long` type, and restrict your usage to the least significant 32 bits.

That will model a 32 bit unsigned integral type.

For longer unsigned types, you'll need to base a solution on `java.math.BigInteger`.

Comment: I have other scenarios for unsigned long as well. So this is still doesn't help me.

Comment: In that case use `Long.toUnsignedString()` as Alex suggested. If nothing else works for you, you will have to develop your own method; you can always get the raw (signed) bytes from the `ByteBuffer`.